# How do i reduce the number of outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, fibonacci

Suppose I input n=5, how do i get the first 5 numbers as the output and not 10?

```
    #fibonacci sequence
n=int(input('Enter number of numbers: '))
a=1
b=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a=a+b
    b=a+b
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Hi, can you add more details to your question? I'm not able to understand what kind of problem statement you're solving.

Comment: i am trying to make a programme for outputting the fibonacci sequence

Answer (score 1):

The way you are adding `a` and `b` in the `for` loop is wrong. If you use `print` twice it will print twice per loop.

```
n=int(input('Enter number of numbers: '))
a=1
b=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a, b = a + b, a
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
n = int(input('Enter number of numbers: '))
def fib(n):
    curr, next_ = 1, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield curr
        curr, next_ = next_, curr + next_
print(list(fib(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input('Enter number of numbers: '))
a=1
b=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a, b = a + b, a
    print(a)
```

The problem with your approach is you go with step 2 each time. For example on one iteration you go from `a=5, b=3` to `a=13, b=8`. So there is 2 * 5 outputs.